# Call method only once every app launch

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

**Hey guys at Stackoverflow!**

I need **your** help. I am looking for a way to call my method **only once** after the application has **launched** and "save" the state of the color of the UIView. At first I will show you my code, that I can explain it in a better way:

> -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
>
> ```
> NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor myWhiteColor],[UIColor myBlueColor],[UIColor myCyanColor],[UIColor myGreenColor],[UIColor myOrangeColor],[UIColor myPurpleColor],[UIColor myRedColor],[UIColor myViolettColor],[UIColor myYellowColor], nil];
>
> NSInteger randomIndex = random() % [colors count];
>
> colorTransparentView.backgroundColor = [colors objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
> colorTransparentView.opaque = NO;
> colorTransparentView.alpha = 1.0;
> ```
>
> }

Now I explain you my issue. 
As you can see, the code above changes the color of the UIView, every time the "viewWillAppear" method was called. The code randomly changes the color of the UIView(in the .xib) which is linked with an IBOulet to the header file. The problem is that every time I get back to the view I will get a different color.

However, I want to set the random color of the `UIView` only once the application started. This color should **stay** until the application was **closed** from the Multitasking. I can't see any way to solve this. I tried to call the code in the `applicationDidFinishedLaunchingWithOptions` method, but I wasn't succsessful.

Also I tried the `dispatch_once` method to call it only once, but as you may think of the color was never called again, so the view got no color the second time loaded.

I really would appreceate if you could help me with this.

Thanks in Advance,

Noah

**EDIT:**

My header:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIView *colorTransparentView;
}


@end
```

Comment: Why not set the color in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: @jlehr it is just the same! It don't make any difference!

Comment: It might help to see the declaration of `colorTransparentView`. Views don't magically lose their background colors at runtime.

Comment: @jlehr It is connected with an IBOutlet to the interfaceBuilder.

Comment: That's not what I asked.

Comment: @jlehr what did you asked for? :D That is the only thing I've set up for the UIView.

Comment: The `UIView` of what? Rather than asking us try to guess what your code does, why not just post the code? It would help to see the contents of your `.h` file -- it sounds as though you may be trying to do something in usual, but again, without seeing the code we can only guess.

Comment: @jlehr look at the edit above!

Comment: people who talked a lot. go and upvote my solution please :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using a static variable? initialise it with 0 and after changing color in your view will appear. set it to 1 and keep checking it.

```
int static colortaken = 0;
int static colorindex;
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

   NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor myWhiteColor],[UIColor myBlueColor],[UIColor myCyanColor],[UIColor myGreenColor],[UIColor myOrangeColor],[UIColor myPurpleColor],[UIColor myRedColor],[UIColor myViolettColor],[UIColor myYellowColor], nil];
   if (colortaken == 0)
   {
      NSInteger randomIndex = random() % [colors count];
      colorindex = randomIndex;
      colorTransparentView.backgroundColor = [colors objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
      colorTransparentView.opaque = NO;
      colorTransparentView.alpha = 1.0; 
   }
   else
   {
      // do nothin  
      colorTransparentView.backgroundColor = [colors objectAtIndex:colorindex];
      colorTransparentView.opaque = NO;
      colorTransparentView.alpha = 1.0;
   }

   // at end
   colortaken = 1;
}
```

Comment: nope! Just like the dispatch_once method! The view loads with color at launch after I change to a different controller and get back there is no color anymore. :(

Answer (score 0):

Use dispatch_once.  You can read up on singleton approaches in general, but this is the recommended approach.